# How can I apply a certain "pressure" (g/cm²) to the ground by dropping a weight?

Tags: pressure, mass-energy

I'm trying to find a way to apply 100g/cm² to the ground (substrate = snow) by dropping a weight from a particular height.

If I drop 250g weight (80cm² area) from 1m, I'll get a velocity of 4.43m/s² and kinetic energy of 2.45 Joules... or 24983 gram force*cm. I could figure out the impact force by assuming a 0.1s impact, but I can't really see that this will help me...?

If i know the area of the weight is 80cm² how can I figure out what the "pressure" is over that area (ultimately get to g/cm²) given that I know the work (gf*cm)?

I think I'm just missing some basic physics principles in trying to think through this - I'd appreciate the help (and thanks).

Comment: You need to know the distance or time over which the falling object decelerates to zero speed.  This will give you an average acceleration, which you can use to estimate an average pressure.  You will not, however, be able to apply a precise pressure by dropping something due to the discontinuity at the initial impact...

Comment: Thanks!  So, 1m is the distance, plus penetration into snow (and that depends on the hardness of the snow).  An average of 110cm in soft fluffy snow, and 100cm on a compact surface.  I just need to be close to 100g/cm², but I'd like to know how to calculate the value based on different sized 'cylinders' that I'll drop.

Comment: In your system of units, is "$100~\rm{ g/cm^2}$" what the rest of us call $10^4 ~\rm{N/m^2}$?

Comment: As @honeste_vivere correctly pointed out, the problem is significantly complicated by the changing force as the snow is compressed, and the fact that as the weight continues to fall, it is picking up a bit more gravitational energy. You have to make an assumption about the force-displacement curve. Perhaps you can explain what you are actually trying to do - maybe you are asking us to solve the wrong problem...

Comment: @RLang - $P \ dA \approx dF$, assuming $P$ is a constant (which it is not here)...

Comment: I'm building on some previous work estimating the sinking depth of wolves in different types of snow (across time and elevation).  A wolf's foot-load is considered to be its weight/area of its foot - so 100g/cm² (on average). Previous work has used methods of "dropping a cylinder that generated a force of 100 g/cm² when penetrating the snow from a 1m height".  As I looked into this method some more, though, it wasn't clear how the authors ensured that they were consistently applying this "force."  Additionally, if I were to replicate it, what should the parameters of the cylinder be (area)?

Comment: @Floris - any other thoughts based on the new information I provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit of basic physics.

If you drop a mass $m$ with area $A$ from a height $h$ onto snow, and it penetrates the snow to a depth $d$, then the ***average pressure*** on the snow during the fall is calculated as follows:

Total distance dropped: $D = h+d$.

Total gravitational energy: $E = mg(h+d)$

Retarding force $F$ acted over distance $d$ to do the same amount of work as gravity:

$$F d = mg(h+d)$$

The force per unit area (average pressure) is then given by:

$$P=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{mg(h+d)}{Ad}$$

Interestingly, the term in the denominator $Ad$ is the *volume* of snow that is compacted, while the term in the numerator is the energy (weight times total height dropped).

Obviously, there are a few things to think about when you do this with "real" snow: in particular, the force will probably change with distance, but as long as you are falling about the same distance (same depth as an actual wolf's footprint) you will have roughly the same physics. Also, as a wolf runs it will may at times have most of its weight on just one foot, not four - although if the snow is soft, it may change to a trot (opposite diagonals), to spread its weight more evenly.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for and I truly appreciate your time.  The units come out as g/cm² * m/s² if i'm not mistaken, but for all intents and purposes, gravity can be considered to be 'environmental' and basically 'ignored'.